# How can I add something like a value_counts() at the bottom of each row in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe which has several columns with custom bins. I would like for the dataframe to include something similar to a value count of the bins after the last row of the group (unique value in another column). I have:

```
     |  Staff  |  Document A     |  Document B     |
     |  Bob    |  Expired        |  Expired        |
     |  Bob    |  Expiring soon  |  On Time        |
     |  Tom    |  On Time        |  Expired        |
     |  Tom    |  Expiring soon  |  On Time        |
     |  Tom    |  Expiring soon  |  Expired        |
     |  Tom    |  On Time        |  On Time        |
```

I would like:

```
     |  Staff            |  Document A     |  Document B     |
     |  Bob              |  Expired        |  Expired        |
     |  Bob              |  Expiring soon  |  On Time        |
     |  Expired          |      1          |      1          |
     |  Expiring soon    |      1          |      0          |
     |  On Time          |      0          |      1          |
     |  Tom              |  On Time        |  Expired        |
     |  Tom              |  Expiring soon  |  On Time        |
     |  Tom              |  Expiring soon  |  Expired        |
     |  Tom              |  On Time        |  On Time        |
     |  Expired          |      0          |      2          |
     |  Expiring soon    |      2          |      0          |
     |  On Time          |      2          |      2          |
```

If that is not practical. I have also exported my dataframe to individual sheets of the same Excel Workbook grouped by Staff. If easier, I could import the workbook into multiple dataframes and add this summary at the bottom of the dataset in Python. So then each sheet would like something like:

```
     |  Staff            |  Document A     |  Document B     |
     |  Bob              |  Expired        |  Expired        |
     |  Bob              |  Expiring soon  |  On Time        |
     |  Expired          |      1          |      1          |
     |  Expiring soon    |      1          |      0          |
     |  On Time          |      0          |      1          |
```

Comment: how does tom have an expired = 1 if he did not have an expired in the original df?

Comment: That was a typo. I don't know how to bring a dataframe into stackoverflow so I just type one up. Nice catch though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` with custom groups. It is best to keep the data in the new column for better processing capabilities later unlike Excel.

```
 df.groupby(['Staff', pd.Categorical(df.Document)]).count()
```

Output

```
                     Document
Staff                        
Bob   Expired               1
      Expiring soon         1
      On Time               0
Tom   Expired               0
      Expiring soon         2
      On Time               2
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not explain myself well. I actually have several similar columns within the dataframe. I have Document A, Document B, Document C, etc. Each with the same bins. So it would be much easier to read the table if they could be placed at the bottom of the dataframe.

Comment: Please clarify your question with relevant data by editing the question

Comment: Edits have been made. Thank you for pointing that out by the way.

Comment: It will be easier to read with the data appended below. But it is not the panda's way of changing the type of data under a column because it will destroy subsequent processing power. For example: In your data how do you count the number of Staff members? @brandooo23

Comment: I understand that it's not exactly tidy, but it's for the sake of presentation and not have to do it on every Excel sheet. As for staff member counts, I do not count the staff, only the result of each document for each staff. That frame is grouped something like df.groupby('Staff')['Document A'].value_counts()

That is done for each document and then I merge each of the dataframes together to make a summary table based on index which is "Staff" @Vishnudev

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea then. Since it's against pandas' basic principle of same `dtype` per column.